# trying to import image through json file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import, jsx

I've been playing around with React and I am currently trying to import an image using a file adress taken from a json file. I'm getting an error that says "Error: Cannot find module '/resources/correspondance.png'"

I've been trying different solutions with the image source but cant figure out the right one.
The method used returns the adress through console log if called.

```
<img src={require(getLogo[0])} alt='' />
```

I have tried this with and without require, also with and withous braces. Some advice?

this is the line from json: "Logo": "/resources/correspondance.png",

Will edit if issue is unclear.

Comment: Don't use `require` for image url string. `require` is only to load JS modules. Try to insert image url string as is.

Comment: The problem is in your path, try use a relative path to the logo.

Comment: if i just use {} nothing happens, it does compile but no img is imported

Comment: It's unclear what do you mean saying "import an image". Because `img` tag imports nothing. It just shows image in a browser. Maybe it would be better to share full code of your component.

Comment: It seems that there is no `correspondance.png` image under `/resources` folder. Maybe it lays somewhere else in your project or is missing at all